# how to create rows in an html table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table with 5 rows and 4 columns, with increasing multiples of a number input. I'm able to successfully get the numbers to print, but all in one column. I thought splitting up the loops would help, but obviously it did not. Any help you can provide would be awesome. Thanks. <3

My question is not the same as the one mentioned. My input is different, my output is different.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<h2>A 5x4 multiples table based on user input</h2>

<script type='text/javascript'>

var num = prompt("Enter Number", "0")
var num = parseInt(num);
var i = 0;

document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="0">');

for(i=1;i<5;i++) {
document.write("<tr><td>"+ num*i +"</td></tr>");
}

for(i=5;i<9;i++) {
document.write("<tr><td>"+ num*i +"</td></tr>");
}

for(i=9;i<12;i++) {
document.write("<tr><td>"+ num*i +"</td></tr>");
}

for(i=12;i<16;i++) {
document.write("<tr><td>"+ num*i +"</td></tr>");
}

for(i=16;i<21;i++) {
document.write("<tr><td>"+ num*i +"</td></tr>");
}

document.write("</table>");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a row each time you run your loop. Instead you should create your row before you loop,then add tsble-cells in the loop and finally add the end row:

```
document.write("<tr>");
for(i=1;i<5;i++) {
    document.write("<td>"+ num*i +"</td>");
}
document.write("</tr>");
```

Do this for all your loops.

Comment: Hmm - when I replace my loops with this, my prompt no longer comes up and therefore a table doesn't populate on the page.